# defineSlots functional component

Tags: vue.js

within a Vue SFC as of 3.3+ slot scope is now type safe with `defineSlots`. Is there a way to provide the same type support for slots when the component is functional and not

```
export default defineComponent({
name: 'MyComponent',
  expose: [],
  setup(_props, { slots }) {
    // const slots = defineSlots<{
    //   default?: (props: {
    //     foo: string[],
    //   }) => unknown,
    // }>()
  }
})
```

Comment: have a look at [`slots`](https://vuejs.org/api/options-rendering.html#slots) option

Answer (score 0):

The second argument in a functional component has `slots` property:

[VUE SFC PLAYGROUND](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

```
<script setup>
import { ref , h} from 'vue'

const msg = ref('Hello World!')

const functionalComponent = (props, {slots}) => {
  return [
   h('div', {}, ['default slot: ', slots.default?.()]),
   h('div', {}, ['second slot: ', slots.second?.()]),
  ];
}
</script>

<template>
  <functional-component>
    <input v-model="msg"/>
    <template #second>{{ msg }}</template>
  </functional-component>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define an object that will serve as the properties for the slot.

```
const slotProps = { foo: ['example1', 'example2'] };

export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  functional: true,
  render(h, { slots }) {
    // Pass the slotProps object to the default slot.
    return h('div', [
      slots.default ? slots.default(slotProps) : '',
    ]);
  },
};
```